# How can I get the mouse wheel vertical scroll rate

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm currently developping a custom control, and, to implement vertical scrolling, I want to be able to fetch the configured vertical scroll rate (described [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/20111/windows-7-scroll-faster-when-rolling-the-mouse-wheel/)). 
I would use this setting to move the control by [X] number of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it from [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES`.

> Retrieves the number of lines to scroll when the vertical mouse wheel
>   is moved. The pvParam parameter must point to a UINT variable that
>   receives the number of lines. The default value is 3.

Comment: C# equivalent (because this is also tagged): `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousewheelscrolllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)